# Поведение скроллбара, как в галерее Контакта

Tags: jquery, html, css

Начал делать jQuery галерею.

1. Как убрать вертикальный скролл?
2. Как его добавить, но чтоб он прокручивал не страницу со всем содержимым, а только само изображение, если оно не вмещается по высоте?

Comment: [overflow][1] вам в помощь


  [1]: http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow

Comment: Подробнее можно?

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

в css есть волшебное свойство

`overflow,overflow-x,overflow-y:<visible>|<hiiden>|<auto>,<scroll>,<inherit>`

Answer (score 2):

Вот здесь это обсуждалось: [The Modal — правильные модальные окна](http://habrahabr.ru/post/148515/).

> Модальное окно по определению блокирует работу пользователя с родительским окном до тех пор, пока пользователь его не закроет. То есть:
>
> - Пользователю нельзя позволять прокручивать страницу под ним.
> - При этом, если содержимого в модальном окне очень много, нужно позволить прокручивать содержимое.
>
> По этому принципу работает просмотр фото в Facebook и Вконтакте и, я считаю, что для модальных окон это правильный вариант.